# How to override navigation bar buttons

Tags: android

Is it possible to override all the buttons in the Android navigation bar?
Is it maybe possible to add a new button?

How can I change the appearance of the buttons? I want to set an other background bitmap.

I am using a Nexus 7.
I just know onBackPressed() but what about the other two buttons?
And how are they called?

Comment: If navigation button is present in the screen itself, then you can hide it by using rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(8);

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to override this methode !

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        OnClick click = new OnClick();
        click.onClick(findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel));
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I just used this methode to handle save event for my form and you can use to handle pushing other keys using `KeyEvent` parameters.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but this method is just for the back button. What about the other buttons?

Comment: I'd imagine there's a variable for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_THEKEYYOUWANT`

Comment: yes, i suppose. but how are these variables called. i know KEYCODE_BACK. what are the names of the other two buttons?

Comment: for menu key you must use 'KEYCODE_MENU' like this :

'
if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
            Toast.makeText(this,"you pressed a key",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
'